# hardware conversion of image pixel format in ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, format, gpu, pixel

I am trying to decode an online rtmp video stream into RGB format frames, and then encoding RGB frames into an online stream.

### Task

Here is what I do now:

> decoding a video stream to get images(RGB) ---> ai model process ---> encoding frames(RGB) to form a video stream in H264

### My scheme

All my code in written in C with **FFmpeg** dependencies. The detailed steps are:

> rtmp/rtsp video stream ---> `AVPacket` ---(nvidia cuda)---> `AVFrame`(nv12 pix fmt) ---> `AVFrame`(RGB pix fmt) ---> AI process.

> `AVFrame`(RGB pix fmt) ---> `AVFrame`(nv12 pix fmt) ---(nvidia cuda)---> `AVPacket` ---> rtmp/rtsp video stream

Now, the decoding and encoding part are run on NVIDIA GPU, which is quite fast.

But the conversion of pixel format between `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` and `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB` is run on CPU, which is astonishingly CPU-consuming cause the size of video frame is 2k.

### My question

So, is there any off-the-shelf method to fulfill the conversion of image pixel format on GPU (especially via cuda) directly?